# Upgradeable pointer (unique_ptr -> shared_ptr)

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

I'm told that `shared_ptr` is much slower than `unique_ptr`, so you should always strive to use `unique_ptr`'s when possible. I have a potential use case where one object will have a single owner the majority of the time, but may have multiple owners in some scenarios. In this case, is there any sort of implementation of a `unique_ptr` that can be upgraded to a `shared_ptr` when needed instead of having everything be declared as a `shared_ptr` in the first place?

IE instead of using `shared_ptr`, would it be more beneficial if I used something like the following if the case of upgrading is very rare, or is there some pitfall I'm not seeing here?

```
class upgrade_ptr<T> {
  shared_ptr<T> shared_;
  unique_ptr<T> unique_;
  upgrade_ptr(T obj) {
    unique_ = unique_ptr<T>(obj);
  }
  shared_ptr<T> share() {
    if (shared_ == nullptr) {
      shared_ = shared_ptr<T>(unique_);
    }
    return shared_;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing it around while it's single ownership, so there's no ref counting involved. Then `shared_ptr` has the same performance as `unique_ptr`, provided you allocate with `make_shared` (it uses slightly more memory though, for the control block). The class appears to complicate things for no advantage. But don't take my word for it wrt. performance, **measure**. That's the first law of optimization, measure.

Comment: Must single- and shared-ownership pointers have the same type, or do they exist in separate components?

Comment: premature optimization? Dont try to get fancy, the stl implementers are pretty efficient. I have built huge projects using nothing but shared_ptr and never seen it as a bottleneck

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr` is slower than `std::unique_ptr` because it keeps track of the number of `std::shared_ptr` instances managing the same object. `std::unique_ptr` instances do not do this. That means that every time a `std::unique_ptr` instance's destructor is called, the managed object is deleted as well, whereas a `std::shared_ptr` instance only deletes the managed object when it is the last instance pointing to this object upon destruction.

With that being said, your upgrade function can look something like this:

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> upgradePointer(std::unique_ptr<T> &u)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(u.release());
}
```

Downgrading, on the other hand, can not be done so easily, because **there is no way** to tell a `std::shared_ptr` to stop managing a certain object.

Hope that helps.